# Jquery click outside the element to hide other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-click-event

Haai. I have a problem. How to I hide this button when I click outside of `<input type="search">`. The `button` show when I click `<input type="search">`but I don't know how to hide the button when we click outside the `<input type="search">`. Any idea?

HTML

```
<input type="search">
<button type="submit" class="search_btn" name="button">Search</button>
```

Jquery

```
 $("input[type='search']").click(function() {
   $(".search_btn").addClass("search_on");
 });
 $("*:not('input[type='search']')").click(function() {
   $(".search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
 });
```

Comment: `div.input[type='search']`  is equal to `<div class="input" type="search"></div>`

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'div.input[type='search']'`

Comment: Sorry, I wrong. Wait the minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use`removeClass`

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id !== 'submitButton' && event.target.id !== "search") {
    $(".search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
  }

})
$("input[type='search']").on({
  click: function() {
    $(".search_btn").addClass("search_on");
  }
});
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
  console.log($("#search").val())
})
```

```css
.search_btn {
  display: none
}

.search_on {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search">
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="search_btn" name="button">Search</button>
```

Comment: @BariqDharmawan No it doesn't work because it makes the button unclickable

Comment: ooh sorry. I just realized it

Comment: @A.Wolff apologies , for the mistake.Have edited the answer

Comment: Okk. Thanks bro. I love it!

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `blur` event.
When you click on the `input`, it receives `focus`, when you leave (by clicking, keyboard interaction, etc.) it loses focus and triggers `blur`. So:

```
$("input[type='search']").blur(function () {
    $(".search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
})
```

It might also be a good idea to use the `focus` event instead of `click` on Line 1 so that users can also tab into the field and have it work correctly:

```
$("input[type='search']").focus(function() {
  $(".search_btn").addClass("search_on");
})

$("input[type='search']").blur(function () {
  $(".search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
});
```

See also:

- https://api.jquery.com/focus/
- https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 3):

Most likely what you want can be accomplished with the `focus` and `blur` events.

```
$("input[type='search']").focus(function() {
  $(".search_btn").addClass("search_on");
});
$("input[type='search']").blur(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(".search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
  }, 50);
});
```

You'll need a timeout to allow the button to still be clicked, since clicking the button will cause the input to be blurred.

Comment: Yeahh. Thanks bro. That's what I need.

Comment: Sorry bro. but the button unclickable. How can I made it clickable

Comment: what is 50? 50s, 50ms, or another?

Comment: @BariqDharmawan 50ms. You can change it if you want.

Comment: @BariqDharmawan you need to increase the value if it doesn't work. But even if it works for you, there is no guarantee that it will work for someone else. So this isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

using event focus and blur:

```
$("input[type='search']").focus(function() {
  $(".search_btn").addClass("search_on");
})

$("input[type='search']").blur(function () {
  $(".search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `focus` and `blur` events. When control is inside the textbox, `focus` event is called. When control leaves the textbox, `blur` event is called.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='search']").focus(function() {
    $("button[type='submit'].search_btn").addClass("search_on");
  })

  $("input[type='search']").blur(function () {
    $("button[type='submit'].search_btn").removeClass("search_on");
  });
});
```

```css
.search_on { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search">
<button type="submit" class="search_btn" name="button">Search</button>
```